# How to remove 3D touch quick action thats added using swift code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have started playing with 3D touch quick actions for my app for iPhone 6S using code from apples developer [site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/Listings/ApplicationShortcuts_AppDelegate_swift.html)

This worked fine, but now i am unable to remove these quick actions.I only made changes to AppDelegate and I have removed this sample code from AppDelegate but quick actions still remain. Info.plist does not have any quick actions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the code, than just delete app from your phone and rerun it.

If you need to do it programmatically for any reason, just call this function

```
func removeAllDynamicQuickActions() {
        UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems?.removeAll()
}
```